# I changed /etc/passwd to git-shell and changed it back, but now shell not working

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, git-shell

I was following the instruction on how to set up a git server [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server), and I removed the ssh access from the `git` user by setting `/etc/passwd` file to `/usr/bin/git-shell`.

Later I found out that I still want to ssh as `git`, so I reset it back to `/bin/sh`.  I could ssh back, but the shell prompt looked all strange today.  Previously, the prompt was

`git@xyz.com $`

but now it's just

`$`

Tab Autocomplete is gone. History is also gone. I am not sure what files got removed when I switched to `git-shell`. How do I recover from this?

Comment: can you please share content of /etc/passwd file here. If not entire file then line where information for git user is shown.

Comment: git:x:1000:1000:git,,,:/home/git:/bin/sh

Comment: I hope you would have tried disconnecting ssh and then reconnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chsh git -s /bin/bash` should fix it (I prefer to use the `chsh` program instead of editing `/etc/passwd` by hand to change an account's login shell)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it was not `/bin/sh` before, try setting it as

```
/bin/bash
```

Comment: This does it. Thanks! :)